# Google play vouchers and redeem codes

Tags: google-play-store

My friend lives in a different country but I want to send them a Google Play voucher or send the redeem code via Facebook.

Would the redeem code work if she lives in a different country and our currency differs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could tell your friend to use some VPN services to get access to US google play. By that way, your friend could easily redeem the code without any problem.